# Trouble copying the string using memcpy

Tags: c++, arrays, string, memcpy

I have a string say `toioyhpknmtlghk`.I want to create a 2-d character array having n rows such that it contains first,second,third sub strings of length n as it's rows.

For example,here **n=5** the sub strings of length 5 are, `toioy` `hpknm` and `tlghk`
so array **arr** should look like

```
t o i o y
h p k n m
t l g h k
```

Now this could have been easier if I copy the characters by looping through the array but here I am trying to use **memcpy** as,

```
int main()
{
  long n;
  cin>>n;
  char a[3][n+1];char str[20];   //I have taken n+1 columns as n for substring and 1 for '\0'
  scanf("%s",str);
  char *p=str;
  memcpy(a[0],p,n);strcat(a[0],"\0");
  p=p+n;
  memcpy(a[1],p,n);strcat(a[1],"\0");
  p=p+n;
  memcpy(a[2],p,n);strcat(a[2],"\0");

  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n",a[i]);
  }

}
```

But on outputting the array following results are obtained,

```
//input
5
toioyhpknmtlghk

//output    
toioy
hpknm{tlghk‼â
tlghk‼â
```

Comment: `cin>>n;` is not valid C. (unless `cin` is an object of integer type, both `cin` and `n` are initialized, and the value of `n` is positive and lower than the width of the type of `cin`, in which case it's a statement with no effect.

Comment: Show the full input/output session

Comment: What should `strcat(a[0],"\0");` do?

Comment: Replace `strcat(a[0],"\0");` by `a[0][n] = '\0';`. Mind the quotes.

Comment: That's not C! Use the correct tags!

Comment: Since when does C++ allow VLAs?

Comment: Don't use `scanf("%s",str);` - may result in buffer overflow

Comment: So the question to you is do you really want to use C++ to solve your problem, or solve your problem using more or less, `C` code?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually I am using c++ ,tag 'C' was put by mistake.I am not that much familiar with c++ strings so just trying to make best use of 
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `strcat(a[0],"\0");` is working on strings which are already terminated by `\0`. Otherwise it doesn't know *where* to append the second string. In your case `a[0]` is not terminated, so the function will induce undefined behavior. You can do the following instead:

```
a[0][n] = '\0';
```

(the same is for the rest of `a` elements)

Comment: Also `"\0"` is not the same as `'\0'`.

Comment: @alk You mean that `"\0"` will actually be *two* zeros?

Comment: Yes!-) Twice as much memory! An array, a `char[2]` not a `char`.

Comment: @alk Actually I think `strcat(whatever, "\0");` should not do anything to `whatever` (if terminated), as `"\0"` is an empty string no matter how long.

Comment: I agree, but still ... ;-)

Comment: @EugeneSh.Still getting undesired output,however when I declare array a as char a[3][8] only then it shows correct output

Comment: @Adityapratapsingh Have you made the change for *all* `a` elements, not only the `a[0]`?

Comment: @EugeneSh.No,I did it only for a[0]

Comment: `a[0]` was just an example. It applies for the rest.